# FPS Player camera cant look left and right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried the last few weeks fix the problem with the camera. Like the title says, the players camera wont look left and right. And why? Because when I move the mouse left and right, the players y rotation rotates the right direction. But the Cameras y rotation is equal to the Players y rotation as a negative number. so, can anyone help me?

I tried literally everything. I expect the camera to rotate in all direction.

Here is the movement and look code:

```
    mX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sensivity * Time.deltaTime;
    mY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sensivity * Time.deltaTime;

    mY = Mathf.Clamp(mY, -89.9f, 89.9f);

    transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * mX/2;
    cam.eulerAngles = Vector3.up * mX/2;
    cam.eulerAngles = Vector3.right * mY;

    float inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float inputY = Input.GetAxis("Fly");
    float inputZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 dirForward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.forward, Vector3.up).normalized;
    Vector3 dirSide = transform.right;
    Vector3 dirUp = Vector3.up;

    Vector3 moveDir = (inputX * dirSide) + (inputY * dirUp) + (inputZ * dirForward);
    transform.position += moveDir * Speed * Time.deltaTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code for my 3d movements. Try it, it should work

```
public class free_cam_view : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    float xr_1 = 0f;
    void Update()
    {
     float y = 2 * Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
               xr_1 -= y;
              xr_1 = Mathf.Clamp(xr_1, -90f, 63f);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xr_1, 0f, 0f); 
    }
}
```

Just add code to move forward by pressing "w"

Comment: thats kinda not that what i searched and it kinda the same as my code